# Join Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop to Windows Domain

Tags: 17.04

How do I join a laptop computer running Ubuntu 17.04 to a windows domain, I am looking for the easiest way as I have limited knowledge on Ubuntu. We're looking at it as an alternative to windows for our desktop computers. what I'm after is a how to guide (screenshots would be helpful) as I have 30 laptops to set up and then 30 workstations plus IT suites if the laptops work successfully.

Comment: As you mention a lot of hosts, you might consider automating the task with [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). I'm using it here to manage Ubuntu 16.04 Workstations and `sssd` for the AD integration (I already have a playbook for this). A good start would be https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html. For screenshots I can recommend this: http://www.wolffhaven45.com/blog/linux/join_ubuntu_workstation_windows_domain/. What exactly do you want to gain from the integration? Only authentication or more?

Comment: Hi Sethos II I am looking for full integration shared drives, printers. we are looking to cut costs and our Microsoft agreement is costing a fortune I can sort that out later just getting them on and on mass is the issue at the minute

Comment: Would you recommend using 16.04 instead.

Comment: I would recommend 16.04 because it is a long term support release and in a corporate environement I would always go for a LTS version. I will provide my playbook with some context as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

## General

As you mention to integrate a large number of hosts, I would recommend you to use some kind of configuration management tool. I use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for such things. Try it manually once and when everything works automate it.

As you also mention to do this in a corporate environment I would suggest to use Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 17.04 because 17.04 is no longterm support release and therefore is only supported until January 2018.

Additionally this question seems well suited for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

## How-tos

A good starting point would be the official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html. I also found this tutorial quite helpful (and it has a lot of screenshots): http://www.wolffhaven45.com/blog/linux/join_ubuntu_workstation_windows_domain/.

## Ansible Playbook

Based on the mentioned How-tos (and a lot others) I created an [Ansible role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#id8) to automate this process. The directory structure is as follows:

```
ansible/
├── adIntegration.yaml
└── roles
    └── ad-integration
        ├── handlers
        │   └── main.yaml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yaml
        └── templates
            ├── etc
            │   ├── krb5.conf.jinja2
            │   ├── realmd.conf.jinja2
            │   └── sssd
            │       └── sssd.conf.jinja2
            └── usr
                └── share
                    └── lightdm
                        └── lightdm.conf.d
                            └── 50-ubuntu.conf.jinja2
```

(I like to put the files in a directory structure resembling the target structure)

Some files are down below, adapt to your needs:

`adintegration.yaml`

```
---
# execute like:
# ansible-playbook ~/ansible/adIntegration.yaml --inventory ~/ansible/production.hosts
# or
# ansible-playbook ~/ansible/adIntegration.yaml -i ~/ansible/production.hosts
- hosts: "ad-integration"
  remote_user: "admin" # change to whatever user you have with sudo rights
  become: yes
  vars_prompt: # the vars are later used for the join
    - name: "ad_admin_name"
      prompt: "username for AD join"
      private: no
    - name: "ad_admin_password"
      prompt: "password for AD"
      private: yes
      confirm: yes
  roles:
    - role: "ad-integration"
...
```

`main.yaml` (handlers)

```
---
- name: "restart sssd"
  service:
    name: "sssd"
    state: "restarted"
  listen: "sssd needs restart"
...
```

`main.yaml` (tasks)

```
---
- name: "install needed packages"
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: "present"
  with_items:
    - "adcli"
    - "krb5-user"
    - "libnss-sss"
    - "libpam-sss"
    - "libwbclient-sssd"
    - "realmd"
    - "sssd"
    - "sssd-tools"
    - "samba-common"
# copy this from a working one
- name: "template krb5.conf"
  template:
    src: "etc/krb5.conf.jinja2"
    dest: "/etc/krb5.conf"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0644"
    backup: yes
- name: "template realmd.conf"
  template:
    src: "etc/realmd.conf.jinja2"
    dest: "/etc/realmd.conf"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0644"
    backup: yes
- name: "join domain"
  shell: "echo '{{ ad_admin_password }}' | realm join COMPANY.COM -U '{{ ad_admin_name }}' --install=/ -v" # --install=/ needed because of realm bug in package detection
  register: "realm_join"
  changed_when: "'Successfully enrolled machine in realm' in realm_join.stderr"
  failed_when: "'Couldn\\'t join realm' in realm_join.stderr"
- name: "template sssd.conf"
  template:
    src: "etc/sssd/sssd.conf.jinja2"
    dest: "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0600"
    backup: yes
  notify: "sssd needs restart"
- name: "activate automatic creation of home directories"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/pam.d/common-session"
    line: "session  optional            pam_mkhomedir.so "
    state: "present"
    insertbefore: "# end of pam-auth-update config"
    backup: yes
- name: "create lightdm directories"
  file:
    path: "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/"
    state: "directory"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0755"
# the important part here is to add greeter-show-manual-login=true under [SeatDefaults]
- name: "activate username on login window"
  template:
    src: "usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf.jinja2"
    dest: "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0644"
    backup: yes
...
```

`realmd.conf.jinja2`

```
[active-directory]
default-client = sssd
os-name = {{ ansible_distribution }}
os-version = {{ ansible_distribution_version }}

[service]
automatic-install = no

[users]
default-home = /home/%D/%U
default-shell = /bin/bash

[company.com]
fully-qualified-names = no
automatic-id-mapping = yes
user-principal = yes
manage-system = no
enumerate = yes
```

`sssd.conf.jinja2`

```
[sssd]
domains = company.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/company.com]
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
ad_domain = company.com
krb5_realm = COMPANY.COM

id_provider = ad
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
enumerate = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False

fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash

# maybe needed for older AD schemes
#ldap_id_mapping = False
#ldap_schema = ad
#ldap_user_object_class = person
#ldap_user_name = msSFU30Name
#ldap_user_uid_number = msSFU30UidNumber
#ldap_user_gid_number = msSFU30GidNumber
#ldap_user_home_directory = msSFU30HomeDirectory
#ldap_user_shell = msSFU30LoginShell
#ldap_user_gecos = displayName
#ldap_group_object_class = group
#ldap_group_name = msSFU30Name
#ldap_group_gid_number = msSFU30GidNumber
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go and report back when successful.